# Response headers not setting on OwinContext

Tags: iis, cors, asp.net-web-api2, owin, jwt

I have created a web api that uses the JWT system using this article [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/). When calling the API from a REST client it works just fine. However when trying to access it from a browser it gives a CORS error since it doesn't send out the correct response headers.

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

*Note that on my controllers CORS works just fine, it just breaks for the OAuthAuthorizationServer.*

**CustomOAuthProvider.cs**

```
public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

    var user = Database.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == context.UserName);

    if (user == null || !BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(context.Password, user.Password))
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    } 

    var companyId = int.Parse(context.OwinContext.Get<string>("company_id"));
    var company = user.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == companyId);

    if (company == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "You don't belong to that company!");
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    } 

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("uue", user.Email));

    var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "audience", company.ServerUrl }
    });

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);

    context.Validated(ticket);
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

However after making the call to obtain the token, I only get back these response headers.

```
Content-Length:1245
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 20 Apr 2016 20:34:40 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I'm assuming you are using the same `Startup.cs` code defined in the liked tutorial.

Try to move the call to `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);` at the top of your `Configuration` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

   HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

   // Web API routes
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

   ConfigureOAuth(app);

   app.UseWebApi(config);

}
```

In Owin every middleware in the pipeline is executed only if the preceding passes through the invocation. For this reason `app.UseCors` is executed only after the `AuthenticationMiddleware` (in your case `OAuthAuthorizationServer`) and only if it does not stop the flow in the pipeline (e.g. OAuth returns a response).

Moving the Cors middleware declaration before other middlewares ensures you that it is executed for each request.

Comment: Doesn't work either, like I said the header I add with the OwinContext.Response.headers doesn't get added. The other controllers on my authorization server work just fine with CORS.

Comment: Just to be sure, try removing every call to `context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });` from your code, and leave only `app.UseCors`.

Comment: I have no clue then, sorry. Try to inspect the server-side error a bit more (response status-code, exceptions, etc.).

Comment: Turned out to be some caching issue that messed with my publishing profiles! Your approach works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you allow CORS in web config

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,DEBUG" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="authorization,content-type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sitename.com/request Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405